# Wrong session variable in query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, session

I have the following code:

```
$insert_stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt, ' . $_SESSION['pid'] . ');
```

I get this **error message**:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'pid' (T_STRING) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\wildfire\includes\register.inc.php on line 86

What is wrong with the pid? Or am I not able to put a session variable there?

Comment: Don't concate session just use `$insert_stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $email, $password, $random_salt,  $_SESSION['pid']);
`

Comment: TL;TR: you're concatenating a session variable into nothing-ness. as the error says: ***syntax error***. That means the code is invalid, not that you're trying to do something that is not allowed. Syntax highlighting is a wonderful thing. Use it.

Comment: now that ^ @EliasVanOotegem is a valid explanation, rather than the low-quality answer given below.